# Does reduceRegion take care of sticking the neighboring tiles?

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-mosaic

Let's say we pull an image on google earth engine where the entire region is spread across two neighboring tiles of Sentinel. i.e. half of the region is in one tile and half of it is on the other tile.

When we do reduceRegion, does Google Earth Engine automatically take care of such event? Or do we need to mosaic/stitch the tiles first and then do reduceRegion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot apply [reduceRegion](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_reduce_region) to ee.ImageCollection (i.e. tiled S2 imagery) - only on individual ee.Image (e.g. mosaiced collection).

Comment: right. I forgot to delete the question after realizing what you said is true. I am on my way to (learn/try to) mosaic images of different tiles that are taken in one day in an imageCollection.